# Making a function according to a formula (Python)

Tags: python, function, math, formula

I am having trouble with the question you see on the included image. With the very little knowledge I have in Python I am struggling to even find out where to begin with this problem. In particular, how do I make the function according to that formula? The user must be able to enter values for x_i and x_(i-1). All answers will be much appreciated. I don't expect full answer, just some idea of how I can begin this...

[image: Here is the question]

Comment: Do you know how to calculate a sum? Do you know how to calculate a square root? If the answer to both is "yes", what's holding you back?

Comment: Python supports list structures, arrays, etc, so you want to start there looking up Python syntax and examples for those. Square root function is just a library call. The summation will be a Python loop structure which is also easy to find examples of online.

Comment: For arguments of your function - read about python lists, after that - try to figure out how to make list of sums (hint - read about list comprehensions), so you can make list [4, 5] out of [1, 2] and [3, 3] like [1 + 3, 2 + 3]. Python is very fun language, I don't think you'll be in trouble to write this function

Comment: To translate the formula into code, start with values in parentheses or brackets and work out. In this case there are two. The first is the difference between two successive x values and the other between y values. Next each of these are squared and then added together. The square root of their sum is then taken, etc. You can write statement of code to do each of these operations one after the other until you've arrive at the final value and completed the translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this down. First, how does one create the function `pathlength`? Like this:

```
def pathlength(x, y):
    return 42   # The length is 42 miles
```

As you can see, it accepts the `x,y` parameters specified in the problem. Rather than compute an answer, it returns a made-up answer. More on how to find the answer in a minute.

The way a user might invoke this function is like so:

```
length = pathlength([0, 7, 9, 5, 2, 0], [0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0])
```

As you can see, I've passed a list of `x` values and a list of `y` values.

Now that we know how to declare the function, and how to invoke the function, all that is left is the math. The problem says that we need to sum the terms of a series. Our first step is to create those terms in a convenient manner. The series runs from `1` to `n-1` (that is, the summation has one fewer steps than our data has.

To represent the values, we can use slice notation:

```
x[1:]  # The X(i) values from 1 to n-1
x[:-1] # The X(i-1) values from 1-1 to n-1-1
```

and similarly for `y`.

It would be convenient to have the two X values and the two Y values related somehow. This is a job for `zip`:

```
zip(x[1:], x[:-1], y[1:], y[:-1])
```

`zip` produces a list of tuples, each tuple is the variables related to a particular value of `i`.

Now to consider each value of `i` in turn:

```
for xi, xi1, yi, yi1 in zip(x[1:], x[:-1], y[1:], y[:-1]):
    pass
```

This loop iterates over all of the entries, but does no actual math.

Now we need to use the Pythagorean formula to determine the two-d distances.

```
total_distance = 0
for xi, xi1, yi, yi1 in zip(x[1:], x[:-1], y[1:], y[:-1]):
    leg_distance = ((xi-xi1)**2+(yi-yi1)**2)**.5
    total_distance = total_distance + leg_distance
```

Finally, we need to communicate that value to our caller:

```
def pathlength(x, y):
    total_distance = 0
    for xi, xi1, yi, yi1 in zip(x[1:], x[:-1], y[1:], y[:-1]):
        leg_distance = ((xi-xi1)**2+(yi-yi1)**2)**.5
        total_distance = total_distance + leg_distance
    return total_distance
```

Hmm. There is another way to do this. Many loop constructs can be replaced by
list comprehensions, as this can. Try googling `python list comprehension` and `python generators` to determine
what *this* does:

```
def pathlength(x,y):
    return sum(
        ((xi-xi1)**2+(yi-yi1)**2)**.5 
        for (xi, xi1, yi, yi1) in zip(x[1:], x[:-1], y[1:], y[:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any image.  It's hard to answer without it.

But if you need to transform a formula in a String to working code, you'll need a parser and expression evaluator.  I'd recommend Googling for a Python expression library and pick the one that suits you best.